# General form of self-composed function

Tags: closed-form, function-and-relation-composition, tetration

Given some $f(x)$ composed with itself $n$ times, how would one go about finding a closed-form expression in terms of $x$ and $n?$

Specifically, I'm trying to find a function in two natural number variables, $f(x,y) = x^{(x^{(...^{(x^x)})^...)})} =$ "$x$ tetrated to the $y$".

Any resources for learning more about function composition at an undergraduate level would be very much appreciated

Comment: I've once put together my own (amateurish) approach to the question of self-composed functions, initialized by the consideration of the tetration - perhaps this is something you (or some later lurker here) likes: open http://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/index.htm and look for the entry  "continuous functional iteration" (https://go.helms-net.de/math/tetdocs/ContinuousfunctionalIteration.pdf)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't have a closed form solution unfortunately.

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterated_function) has some good information on function iteration, and has a section on techniques to find closed forms.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/756446)

Comment: @HarshKumar The question asks for a closed form solution. There isn't a known closed form solution.